# Equation seems to violate transitive property

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, sagemath

I have some function, $f(x)=\sin(mx)\cos(nx)$. I've tried rewriting this using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \sin mx \cos nx \\
&= \frac{e^{imx} - e^{-imx}}{2i} \times \frac{e^{inx} + e^{-inx}}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{4i} \left[\left( e^{imx} - e^{-imx} \right)
  \times \left( e^{inx} + e^{-inx} \right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4 i} \left(e^{ix(m+n)}
  + e^{ix(m-n)} - e^{ix(n-m)}
  - e^{-ix(m+n)}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, something seems to be wrong in that last step. When I check the equalities with sagemath:

```
x=var('x')
m=var('m')
n=var('n')
f(x)=sin(m*x)*cos(n*x)
g(x)=((exp(I*m*x)-exp(-I*m*x))*(exp(I*n*x)+exp(-I*n*x)))/(4*I)
h(x)=(exp(I*x*(m+n))+exp(I*x*(m-n))-exp(I*x*(n-m))-exp(-I*x*(m+n)))/(4*I)
bool(f(x)==g(x))
bool(g(x)==h(x))
bool(f(x)==h(x))
```

I get the result:

```
True
True
False
```

In other words, it's telling me that
$$
\sin mx \cos nx = \frac{1}{4i} \left[\left( e^{imx} - e^{-imx} \right)
  \times \left( e^{inx} + e^{-inx} \right)\right]
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{4i} \left[\left( e^{imx} - e^{-imx} \right)
  \times \left( e^{inx} + e^{-inx} \right)\right] = \frac{1}{4 i} \left(e^{ix(m+n)}
  + e^{ix(m-n)} - e^{ix(n-m)}
  - e^{-ix(m+n)}\right)
$$
but
$$
\sin mx \cos nx \neq \frac{1}{4 i} \left(e^{ix(m+n)}
  + e^{ix(m-n)} - e^{ix(n-m)}
  - e^{-ix(m+n)}\right)
$$
How is this possible? Did I make some error in the last step? Does sage have any introspection capabilities to elucidate why this is the case?

Comment: See  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the first equation in your link is what I simplified $f(x)$ to when I kept going. However, doesn't that just tell me that all of my equations are correct? Why am I seeing the inequality? Is there some assumption I'm not aware of in Euler's formula or the Werner formulas?

Comment: Looks like a bug in sage.

Comment: I've submitted a [bug report](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/28780#ticket) with sage.

Comment: Just as a side note, Sage returns `False` in such situations when it cannot prove `True`.  So false is not true, not verifiably false.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I've tried to experiment just a tad there.